# How to reply to declined flags?

Tags: discussion

I recently flagged a question and the flag was declined without explanation. The flagged question was clearly, from my point of view, a "do the job for me" question. Is there any way to reply to de declination of the flag?

The flagged question is like this: "Lets say i have a custom post type and I want to do *this*, it is possible?"

No code and no more explanation, only what *I have* and what *I want*.

If you need a link to the question just say and I will post the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking here is fine for these cases. Other users might find themselves in the same situation, so it is better to make that public.

I declined the flag on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113878/multiple-single-templates), because a moderator intervention was not needed.

Sure, it is currently not a good question. But there are comments, the user responds, tried to improve the question … no need to discourage the asker at this point with a binding moderator close vote. If it has to be closed, the community should do it.

[Moderators are human exception handlers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), not a tool to circumvent the missing reputation for regular close votes.

For the sake of completeness: Flags on already closed questions will be dismissed almost always. These problems are solved already.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, link to a question would be helpful for context.

In general flags are for moderator discretion. Close votes and such are community mechanisms, they work by themselves without need for moderator involvement. Flags are requests for moderator to *take a look*, they do not *oblige* moderators to take action or discuss them.

In most cases flags should only be used for situations that clearly require moderator involvement or some kind of fast action for which community tools are too slow.